# Android - how to set keystore

Tags: android

I'm running a sample application that has a map component to it.

The app launch find, but I don't see the map loading.

I read sometime ago that it might be caused by keystore mismatch?
How do I set keystore? Been trying to find it from google and eclipse but can't find where I can change that.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah found it.
It's in Preferences->Android->Build->default keystore